# Building a device tree to run a Linux kernel on a Rockchip rk3288 board

Tags: android, linux-kernel, device-tree

I am trying to run a Linux kernel on a Rockchip rk3288 board.

This boards runs a native Android kernel. I extracted the Device Tree Source (DTS) from Android to use it as reference to build a custom DTS for the Linux kernel, following this steps:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/dtb
$ adb pull /proc/device-tree/ /tmp/dtb
$ dtc -I fs -O dts /tmp/dtb/ > /tmp/android.dts
```

Using *android.dts* as a basis I am trying to write a custom *linux.dts* to run Linux kernel 4.4.103 on my board. Linux kernel sources can be downloaded from this repo:

```
git://github.com/rockchip-linux/kernel.git
```

Using my custom *linux.dts* the Linux kernel boots, it mounts a root filesystem fine, the login (serial) console appears, and even the ethernet device works as expected.

But I have power problems with the USB-OTG and with the mini-pci-e. Using a multimeter checked the USB-OTG connector receives 0V when running my Linux kernel, but it receives 4.8V when running the Android kernel. Also, the mini-pci-e receives 0V when running the Linux kernel, but it received 3.75V when running the Android kernel.

I don't know what GPIO lines should be managed to enable power on these two devices. My experience working device trees is quite limited, so any advice with this could be really helpful. Thanks a lot in advance! :)

This is the current *linux.dts* version:

```
/dts-v1/;
#include <dt-bindings/clock/rockchip,rk808.h>
#include "rk3288.dtsi"
/ {
    model = "Linux RK3288";
    compatible = "rockchip,rk3288-merrii-k2", "rockchip,rk3288";
    memory {
        reg = <0x0 0x0 0x0 0x80000000>;
        device_type = "memory";
    };
    ext_gmac: external-gmac-clock {
        compatible = "fixed-clock";
        #clock-cells = <0>;
        clock-frequency = <125000000>;
        clock-output-names = "ext_gmac";
    };
    sdio_pwrseq: sdio-pwrseq {
        compatible = "mmc-pwrseq-simple";
        clocks = <&rk808 RK808_CLKOUT1>;
        clock-names = "ext_clock";
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&wifi_enable_h>;
        reset-gpios = <&gpio4 28 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
    };
    vcc_5v: usb-regulator {
        compatible = "regulator-fixed";
        regulator-name = "vcc_5v";
        regulator-min-microvolt = <5000000>;
        regulator-max-microvolt = <5000000>;
        regulator-always-on;
        regulator-boot-on;
        vin-supply = <&vcc_sys>;
    };
    vcc_host_5v: usb-host-regulator {
        compatible = "regulator-fixed";
        enable-active-high;
        gpio = <&gpio0 14 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&host_vbus_drv>;
        regulator-name = "vcc_host_5v";
        regulator-min-microvolt = <5000000>;
        regulator-max-microvolt = <5000000>;
        regulator-always-on;
        vin-supply = <&vcc_5v>;
    };
    vcc_otg_5v: usb-otg-regulator {
        compatible = "regulator-fixed";
        enable-active-high;
        gpio = <&gpio0 12 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&otg_vbus_drv>;
        regulator-name = "vcc_otg_5v";
        regulator-min-microvolt = <5000000>;
        regulator-max-microvolt = <5000000>;
        regulator-always-on;
        vin-supply = <&vcc_5v>;
    };
    vcc_sys: vsys-regulator {
        compatible = "regulator-fixed";
        regulator-name = "vcc_sys";
        regulator-min-microvolt = <5000000>;
        regulator-max-microvolt = <5000000>;
        regulator-always-on;
        regulator-boot-on;
    };
    usb_control {
        compatible = "rockchip,rk3288-usb-control";
        host_drv_gpio = <&gpio0 14 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
        otg_drv_gpio = <&gpio0 12 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
        rockchip,remote_wakeup;
        rockchip,usb_irq_wakeup;
    };
};
&hdmi {
    status = "okay";
    rockchip,cec_enable = <0>;
    rockchip,hdcp_enable = <0>;
    rockchip,defaultmode = <16>;
};
&dmc {
    status = "okay";
};
&cpu0 {
    cpu0-supply = <&vdd_cpu>;
    enable-method = "psci";
};
&cpu1 {
    enable-method = "psci";
};
&cpu2 {
    enable-method = "psci";
};
&cpu3 {
    enable-method = "psci";
};
&pwm0 {
    status = "okay";
};
&pwm1 {
    status = "okay";
};
&emmc {
    bus-width = <8>;
    cap-mmc-highspeed;
    disable-wp;
    non-removable;
    num-slots = <1>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&emmc_clk &emmc_cmd &emmc_pwr &emmc_bus8>;
    status = "okay";
};
&sdmmc {
    bus-width = <4>;
    cap-mmc-highspeed;
    cap-sd-highspeed;
    card-detect-delay = <200>;
    disable-wp;
    num-slots = <1>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&sdmmc_clk &sdmmc_cmd &sdmmc_cd &sdmmc_bus4>;
    status = "okay";
    supports-sd;
    vmmc-supply = <&vcc_sd>;
    vqmmc-supply = <&vccio_sd>;
};
&sdio0 {
    status = "okay";
    clock-frequency = <50000000>;
    clock-freq-min-max = <200000 50000000>;
    bus-width = <4>;
    cap-sd-highspeed;
    cap-sdio-irq;
    disable-wp;
    keep-power-in-suspend;
    mmc-pwrseq = <&sdio_pwrseq>;
    non-removable;
    num-slots = <1>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&sdio0_bus4 &sdio0_cmd &sdio0_clk>;
    supports-sdio;
};
&gmac {
    assigned-clocks = <&cru SCLK_MAC>;
    assigned-clock-parents = <&ext_gmac>;
    clock_in_out = "input";
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&rmii_pins>;
    phy-supply = <&vcc_lan>;
    phy-mode = "rmii";
    rx_delay = <0x20>;
    tx_delay = <0x30>;
    status = "okay";
    snps,reset-gpio = <&gpio4 7 0>;
};
&gpu {
    mali-supply = <&vdd_gpu>;
    status = "okay";
};
&hevc_service {
    status = "okay";
};
&i2c0 {
    status = "okay";
    clock-frequency = <400000>;
    rk808: pmic@1b {
        compatible = "rockchip,rk808";
        reg = <0x1b>;
        status = "okay";
        interrupt-parent = <&gpio0>;
        interrupts = <4 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_LOW>;
        #clock-cells = <1>;
        clock-output-names = "rk808-clkout1", "rk808-clkout2";
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&pmic_int &global_pwroff>;
        rockchip,system-power-controller;
        wakeup-source;
        vcc1-supply = <&vcc_sys>;
        vcc2-supply = <&vcc_sys>;
        vcc3-supply = <&vcc_sys>;
        vcc4-supply = <&vcc_sys>;
        vcc6-supply = <&vcc_sys>;
        vcc7-supply = <&vcc_sys>;
        vcc8-supply = <&vcc_io>;
        vcc9-supply = <&vcc_io>;
        vcc10-supply = <&vcc_io>;
        vcc11-supply = <&vcc_io>;
        vcc12-supply = <&vcc_io>;
        vddio-supply = <&vcc_io>;
        regulators {
            vdd_cpu: DCDC_REG1 {
                regulator-always-on;
                regulator-boot-on;
                regulator-min-microvolt = <900000>;
                regulator-max-microvolt = <1500000>;
                regulator-name = "vdd_arm";
                regulator-state-mem {
                    regulator-off-in-suspend;
                };
            };
            vdd_gpu: DCDC_REG2 {
                regulator-always-on;
                regulator-boot-on;
                regulator-min-microvolt = <900000>;
                regulator-max-microvolt = <1500000>;
                regulator-name = "vdd_gpu";
                regulator-ramp-delay = <6000>;
                regulator-state-mem {
                    regulator-on-in-suspend;
                    regulator-suspend-microvolt = <1100000>;
                };
            };
            vcc_ddr: DCDC_REG3 {
                regulator-always-on;
                regulator-boot-on;
                regulator-name = "vcc_ddr";
                regulator-state-mem {
                    regulator-on-in-suspend;
                };
            };
            vcc_io: DCDC_REG4 {
                regulator-always-on;
                regulator-boot-on;
                regulator-min-microvolt = <3300000>;
                regulator-max-microvolt = <3300000>;
                regulator-name = "vcc_io";
                regulator-state-mem {
                    regulator-on-in-suspend;
                    regulator-suspend-microvolt = <3300000>;
                };
            };
            vccio_pmu: LDO_REG1 {
                regulator-always-on;
                regulator-boot-on;
                regulator-min-microvolt = <3300000>;
                regulator-max-microvolt = <3300000>;
                regulator-name = "vccio_pmu";
                regulator-state-mem {
                    regulator-on-in-suspend;
                    regulator-suspend-microvolt = <3300000>;
                };
            };
            vcca_33: LDO_REG2 {
                regulator-always-on;
                regulator-boot-on;
                regulator-min-microvolt = <3300000>;
                regulator-max-microvolt = <3300000>;
                regulator-name = "vcca_33";
                regulator-state-mem {
                    regulator-off-in-suspend;
                };
            };
            vdd_10: LDO_REG3 {
                regulator-always-on;
                regulator-boot-on;
                regulator-min-microvolt = <1000000>;
                regulator-max-microvolt = <1000000>;
                regulator-name = "vdd_10";
                regulator-state-mem {
                    regulator-on-in-suspend;
                    regulator-suspend-microvolt = <1000000>;
                };
            };
            vcc_wl: LDO_REG4 {
                regulator-always-on;
                regulator-boot-on;
                regulator-min-microvolt = <1800000>;
                regulator-max-microvolt = <1800000>;
                regulator-name = "vcc_wl";
                regulator-state-mem {
                    regulator-on-in-suspend;
                    regulator-suspend-microvolt = <1800000>;
                };
            };
            vccio_sd: LDO_REG5 {
                regulator-always-on;
                regulator-boot-on;
                regulator-min-microvolt = <1800000>;
                regulator-max-microvolt = <3300000>;
                regulator-name = "vccio_sd";
                regulator-state-mem {
                    regulator-on-in-suspend;
                    regulator-suspend-microvolt = <3300000>;
                };
            };
            vdd10_lcd: LDO_REG6 {
                regulator-always-on;
                regulator-boot-on;
                regulator-min-microvolt = <1000000>;
                regulator-max-microvolt = <1000000>;
                regulator-name = "vdd10_lcd";
                regulator-state-mem {
                    regulator-on-in-suspend;
                    regulator-suspend-microvolt = <1000000>;
                };
            };
            vcc_18: LDO_REG7 {
                regulator-always-on;
                regulator-boot-on;
                regulator-min-microvolt = <1800000>;
                regulator-max-microvolt = <1800000>;
                regulator-name = "vcc_18";
                regulator-state-mem {
                    regulator-on-in-suspend;
                    regulator-suspend-microvolt = <1800000>;
                };
            };
            vcc18_lcd: LDO_REG8 {
                regulator-always-on;
                regulator-boot-on;
                regulator-min-microvolt = <1800000>;
                regulator-max-microvolt = <1800000>;
                regulator-name = "vcc18_lcd";
                regulator-state-mem {
                    regulator-on-in-suspend;
                    regulator-suspend-microvolt = <1800000>;
                };
            };
            vcc_sd: SWITCH_REG1 {
                regulator-always-on;
                regulator-boot-on;
                regulator-name = "vcc_sd";
                regulator-state-mem {
                    regulator-on-in-suspend;
                };
            };
            vcc_lan: SWITCH_REG2 {
                regulator-always-on;
                regulator-boot-on;
                regulator-name = "vcc_lan";
                regulator-state-mem {
                    regulator-on-in-suspend;
                };
            };
        };
    };
};
&i2c1 {
    status = "okay";
};
&i2c2 {
    status = "okay";
};
&i2c3 {
    status = "okay";
};
&i2c4 {
    status = "okay";
};
&i2c5 {
    status = "disabled";
};
&i2s {
    #sound-dai-cells = <0>;
    status = "okay";
};
&io_domains {
    status = "okay";
};
&uart0 {
    status = "okay";
};
&uart1 {
    status = "okay";
};
&uart2 {
    status = "okay";
};
&uart3 {
    status = "okay";
};
&uart4 {
    status = "okay";
};
&usbphy {
    status = "okay";
};
&usb_host0_ehci {
    status = "okay";
    compatible = "rockchip,rk3288_rk_ehci_host";
};
&usb_host0_ohci {
    status = "okay";
};
&usb_host1 {
    status = "okay";
};
&usb_otg {
    status = "okay";
};
&vopb {
    status = "okay";
};
&vopb_mmu {
    status = "okay";
};
&vopl {
    status = "okay";
};
&vopl_mmu {
    status = "okay";
};
&vpu_service {
    status = "okay";
};
&wdt {
    status = "okay";
};
&pinctrl {
    pcfg_output_high: pcfg-output-high {
        output-high;
    };
    pcfg_output_low: pcfg-output-low {
        output-low;
    };
    pmic {
        pmic_int: pmic-int {
            rockchip,pins = <RK_GPIO0 4 RK_FUNC_GPIO &pcfg_pull_up>;
        };
    };
    sdio-pwrseq {
        wifi_enable_h: wifi-enable-h {
            rockchip,pins = <RK_GPIO4 28 RK_FUNC_GPIO &pcfg_pull_none>;
        };
    };
    usb_host {
        host_vbus_drv: host-vbus-drv {
            rockchip,pins = <RK_GPIO0 14 RK_FUNC_GPIO &pcfg_pull_none>;
        };
    };
    usb_otg {
        otg_vbus_drv: otg-vbus-drv {
            rockchip,pins = <RK_GPIO0 12 RK_FUNC_GPIO &pcfg_pull_none>;
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: Hi, after all this time, did you manage to solve the problem?